# online java compile shows the error like this

Tags: java, online-compilation

```
static void isPrime (int n) 
 {      int f;
        for(int i=2;i<=Math.sqrt(n);i++)
        {
            if(n % i == 0)
            {
                f = 1;
            }
        }
        if(n == 1 || f == 1)
        {
            System.out.println("No"); 
        }
        else
         System.out.println("Yes");

 }
```

Compilation Error

```
Compilation Error:
```

prog.java:42: error: variable f might not have been initialized
            if(n == 1 || f == 1)
                         ^
1 error

Comment: Just change `int f;` to `int f = 0;`

Comment: Simply write `int f = 0;` before you use it.

Comment: that means java doesn't initializes with default value

Answer (score 2):

In .NET integers and other value types always have default values. So in C# variable 'f' would have the default integer value of 0.

I guess Java is different... To get rid of this compile error, simply assign a value to f.

In example:

```
int f = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just initialize it f to zero.

```
static void isPrime (int n) {      
    int f=0;

    for(int i=2;i<=Math.sqrt(n);i++){
        if(n % i == 0){
            f = 1;
        }
    }

    if(n == 1 || f == 1){
        System.out.println("No"); 
    }else
        System.out.println("Yes");

 }
```